# Is it possible to do a redirect via google in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

Good afternoon. Actually the question in the header) tricky Question) in what Sense. I find in Google for example on request website Darkside.ru the link to it approximately so
`https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwjq-Ync2qvSAhWBuSwKHZcpAnoQFggaMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.darkside.ru%2F&usg=AFQjCNFq5_mwVurUI3WvQCJ2M9FxNvq8ew&sig2=lmRXhpBWVSeE3KUAr8SepQ&bvm=bv.148073327,d.bGg`

So here, have this link to do a redirect from another site via iFrame. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Google do not allow any of their sites or services to be displayed through an iframe (excluding content they give an embed option for like youtube videos or Google Calendars)